# South Carolina state income tax

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, south-carolina, new-hampshire

My husband and I do not share residency.  I am a resident of South Carolina and he is a resident of New Hampshire. We do file our federal income taxes as married filing joint.  There is no state income tax in NH which is where his income is derived, he works out of the house. I have little income earned in SC. How would we file the state returns?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

From the South Carolina Department of Revenue, Individual Income Tax FAQ

https://dor.sc.gov/tax/individual-income/faq

> **What is the filing requirement if one taxpayer is a resident of South Carolina and one is not?**
>
> If you file married filing jointly for federal purposes, you will also file married filing jointly for South Carolina purposes. If one taxpayer is a resident of South Carolina and one is not, file the SC1040 with the accompanying Schedule NR. Column A of the Schedule NR is the income from your federal return and Column B of the Schedule NR includes only the income earned while a resident of South Carolina or income earned from South Carolina sources.

So you'll need to submit as married filing jointly.